# Making a material-ui dialog draggable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use material-ui Dialog feature.

[Dialog doc](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog)

We need to make the dialog draggable across the view port.
As per below issue, material-ui doesn't have this functionality by default.

[Issue here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4563)

I tried using  [react-draggable](https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable)
by enclosing the dialog with the draggable component. It doesnt work. Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have used react-draggable before. Can you share your code as well

Comment: <Draggable><Dialog {...props}><div>Dialog content</div></Dialog></Draggable>

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";
...

const PaperComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <Draggable
      handle="#draggable-dialog-title"
      cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}
    >
      <Paper {...props} />
    </Draggable>
  );
}
...

<Dialog PaperComponent={PaperComponent} {...otherDialogProps}>
  <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: "move" }} id="draggable-dialog-title">
    Title
  </DialogTitle>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

SO, after a lot of tries, I gave up on material UI dialog and wrote my own modal.
react-draggable works as expected on that.